# How do I make whole words optional in the regex?

Tags: regex, go

Namely, I wanted to customize my regex to recognize the following things `apple and lemon`, `apple lemon`, `apple and` and `apple`. I want the words `and` and `lemon` to be optional, currently I only managed to make `and` optional but not `lemon`.

**It would be great if it's achievable with the current format of the regex.**

Regex:

```
\b([a][\W_]*?)+([p][\W_]*?)+([p][\W_]*?)+([l][\W_]*?)+([e][\W_]*?)+(([a][\W_]*?)+([n][\W_]*?)+([d][\W_]*?))?([l][\W_]*?)+([e][\W_]*?)+([m][\W_]*?)+([o][\W_]*?)+([n][\W_]*?)+\b
```

Regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/Wte6Gg/2

Comment: how is that different than matching just `apple`?

Comment: I mean... just `^apple(?: and)?(?: lemon)?$`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following expression needs to start with "apple", then the words "lemon" and "and" can follow, if they follow both, they need to be in the order "and lemon"
Does that help?

`\b(apple)( ?and)?( ?lemon)?\b`

https://regex101.com/r/gyj0yY/1

---

**EDIT**

In your format the following should work:

`\b([a][\W_]*?)+([p][\W_]*?)+([p][\W_]*?)+([l][\W_]*?)+([e][\W_]*?)+(([\W_]*)([a][\W_]*?)+([n][\W_]*?)+([d][\W_]*?)+)?(([\W_]*)([l][\W_]*?)+([e][\W_]*?)+([m][\W_]*?)+([o][\W_]*?)+([n][\W_]*?)+)?\b`

https://regex101.com/r/5wPyJ1/1

If that is what you were looking for, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: I would like to keep the format of the regex, how would it look like?

Answer (score 1):

This is a more general solution - using two words, optionally joined by an 'and'

https://regex101.com/r/Z2TZ7T/1

[image]